# Clear Button wont work with Upload in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJs and am currently working on creating a file upload script.
I searched the web and combined a few scripts to achieve the code below.

My problem is that the clear button should clear the filename on click and remove the file from the queue.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>   

</head>

<body ng-app = "myApp">

  <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">

     <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile" file-select="file"/>

    <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
     <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
  </div>

  <script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

     app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', 'fileSelect', function($scope, fileUpload, fileSelect){
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };

            $scope.clear = function() {
            $scope.file = null;
            };
        }]);

     app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }

        };
     }]);

    app.directive('fileSelect', function() {

            return function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
                var selector = $parse(attrs.fileSelect);
                var modelSelector = elem.append(selector);

                selector.bind('change', function( event ) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope[ attrs.fileSelect ] = event.originalEvent.target.files;
                    });
                });
                scope.$watch(attrs.fileSelect, function(file) {
                selector.val(file);
                });
            };
    });

     app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })

           .success(function(){
           })

           .error(function(){
           });
        }
     }]);



   </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try  $scope.file = ""; in clear()

Comment: @TirthrajBarot this doesnt work, i already tried it.

Comment: what error does it show in the console?

Comment: I tried building a plunker with your code but got a series of errors in the console just on startup. For instance, 'fileSelect' uses $parse but you haven't injected it. Another "selector.val is not a function".  I'd make sure you resolve any startup errors before trying to solve this specific issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself. Added one more function too.

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" >

<table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2"
        rules="all" border="0" id="gridSwipeApp" >

    <tr style="background-color: #009ca6; color: white;" ng-repeat="item in items"><a ng-click="getId(item)">
    {{item.content}}
    </a>
        <td>
            <div file-select="file" file-model="myFile"></div></td>

        <td><button ng-click="clear($index)" ng-model="activeItem.clear">clear</button></td>
        <td><button ng-click="uploadFile()" ng-model="activeItem.uploadFile"> Upload</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<button type="button" ng-click="addMore()">Add More</button>


</div>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  var template = '<input type="file" name="files"/>'; 

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.items=[{
    id: 1,
    myFile: 'item1',
    clear: 'clearButton1',
    uploadFile: 'uploadbutton1',
}];

$scope.activeItem = {
        myFile: '',
        clear: '',
        uploadFile: '',
}

$scope.addMore = function(){
    $scope.activeItem.id = $scope.items.length + 1;
    $scope.items.push($scope.activeItem);
    $scope.activeItem ={}

}

$scope.file = null;
$scope.clear = function(index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index,1);
    $scope.file = null;
 };
});

app.directive('fileSelect', function() {

return function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
var selector = $( template );
elem.append(selector);
selector.bind('change', function( event ) {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    scope[ attrs.fileSelect ] = event.originalEvent.target.files;
   });
 });
 scope.$watch(attrs.fileSelect, function(file) {
  selector.val(file);
  });
 };
});

app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
 return {
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
      var modelSetter = model.assign;

      element.bind('change', function(){
         scope.$apply(function(){
            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
         });
      });
   }

 };
}]);

app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
   var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('file', file);

   $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
   })

   .success(function(){
   })

   .error(function(){
   });
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**clear** function should be defined as below

```
$scope.clear = function () {
    angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
};
```

Check the snippet below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.uploadFile = function(){
   var file = $scope.myFile;

   console.log('file is ' );
   console.dir(file);

   var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
   fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
  };

  $scope.clear = function () {
   angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
  };

 }]);
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app = "myApp">

 <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">

  <input type = "file" ng-model = "myFile" file-select="file"/>

  <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
 </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: what worked for me was $scope.file = null; in the clear(); Thanks for your help though. It guided me in the right direction.

Comment: yes that works well Nirbhay.. That would have been my first answer ... but when you use any directive with it, that won't work.. @NirbhayTandon

Comment: But still i would be happy if you could mark me correct &or vote me up for this answer... @NirbhayTandon

Comment: You got 2 voteups from me! You deserved that! @NirbhayTandon